# How to change text to what it's selected in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a menu that contains 3 items. How can I change that the text to what it's selected from the menu?

**HTML**

```
<div id="dropdown-container">
<div id="index-tab" onclick="toggleMenu()"><a href="#">1</a></div>
    <ul id="dropdown">
        <li ><a href="#"><span class="current-browse">1</span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-items">
                <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">2</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown-item""><a href="#">3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
function toggleMenu() {
var dropDown = document.getElementById('dropdown');    
if(dropdown.style.display == "block") { 
     dropdown.style.display = "none";
} else { 
     dropdown.style.display = "block";
   } 
}
```

For example the menu currently showing:

1

1

2

3

If selected 2, it will show:

2

2

1

3

If selected 3 it will show :

3

3

1

2

Comment: Where's the `toggleMenu()` function?

Comment: @zer00ne the toggleMenu function I currently have only show/hides the menu. I'll add it in.

Comment: Ok, review my answer, let me know if it's what you were after or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added `toggleSelection()` function:

1. `event.preventDefault();` used to prevent links default action which is jumping to a location.
2. `selectedItem` references `event.target` (i.e. the element that was actually clicked), which is either the one of the `.dropdown-item`s.
3. There's multiple exchanges between elements based on the `.textContent` of the `selectedItem`. At this point, `#current-browse`, and `#index-tab a` (the link in `#index-tab`) have a new `.textContent` and `selectedItem` has the previous item number.
4. All of that will not happen until `#dropdown` is clicked on and the `event.target` is determined. this is possible by the eventListener:

   ```
      dropDown.addEventListener('click', toggleSelection, false);
   ```

#### SNIPPET

```js
function toggleMenu() {
  var dropDown = document.getElementById('dropdown');
  if (dropDown.style.display == "block") {
    dropDown.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    dropDown.style.display = "block";
  }
}

function toggleSelection(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var selectedItem = event.target;
  var targetItem = selectedItem.textContent;
  var currentItem = document.getElementById('current-browse');
  var prevItem = currentItem.textContent;
  var extLink = document.querySelector('#index-tab a');
  currentItem.textContent = targetItem;
  extLink.textContent = targetItem;
  selectedItem.textContent = prevItem;
}

var dropDown = document.getElementById('dropdown');

dropDown.addEventListener('click', toggleSelection, false);
```

```html
<div id="dropdown-container">
  <div id="index-tab" onclick="toggleMenu()"><a href="#">1</a>
  </div>
  <ul id="dropdown">
    <li><a href="#"><span id="current-browse">1</span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-items">
        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

#### REFERENCE

[addEventListener vs. onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6348597/2813224)

['this' and EventHandlers](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-this-event-handlers/)

Comment: Where do I add the line  ***dropDown.addEventListener('click', toggleSelection, false);*** to?

Comment: It'll do it's job right where it is right now, is it not working for you or are you wondering how it'll fit with the rest of your code?

Comment: I got it working now. Thank you. I just didn't put the code at the end of the HTML as Roger Garstang said.

Comment: Excellent, I'm glad you have sorted it out. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

Are you wanting to set the text of index-tab or the text of the current-browse span?  Either way you need some click handlers on the li items that gets the element with the id or class of whichever one you want to set (Will need to get the anchor child of the index-tab div if it is used).  Then replace the text element of the anchor or span.  jQuery will make it a bit easier, but can be done either way. The jQuery example given will need to get the anchor child to then set text, and doing it when showing the menu is not what you want since no item is clicked yet.

Comment: I want both index-tab and current-browse span to be set the same.

Comment: OK,  zer00ne's code should work for you then,  or at least get you in the right direction.  Just put it in a script file or script block.  I usually like files to make debugging in Developer Console easier.  Put it at end of HTML so elements are there to attach the event to.

Answer (score 0):

you need to write the `toggleMenu()` in a way that it changes the text of `index-tab` based on the value of dropdown:

```
$("#index-tab").text($(".dropdown-item option:selected").text())
```

Comment: can you show me the JavaScript interpretation of the code above?

Comment: @Fortytwo that is JavaScript. It's jquery. You should put this line in the toggleMenu function.